# Why is there moisture under this PVC pipe attached to my hot water heater?

Tags: plumbing, leaks

I just noticed this wetness, but it may have been going on a long time. Is it normal? There’s no drain in my basement, just a rough dirt and stone floor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If that pipe just runs down to the floor, that water heater was not installed correctly.  That appears to be a heat pump based water heater, and they basically have a small air conditioning unit on top of them that condenses water from the air as it runs.  Just like a home air conditioner, the water needs to drain somewhere.

Draining this onto the floor means that it will almost always be wet, which is going to cause mold and mildew.  They make condensate pumps that can pump the water up to another drain or to the outside of the house if you don't have a drain available nearby.

So, the roundabout answer is that, yes, its normal for the water heater to produce that moisture, but it should be properly dealt with rather than just puddling on the floor.

Comment: Or it's a fuel burning heater with a condensing section which extracts further heat from the exhaust gasses. Those also produce condensate which needs to be dealt with.